# Setting SFTP Sublime Text 3 for EC2 Amazon Linux Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ftp, sublimetext3, sftp

I have been trying to set up a remote (FTP) access to some playground files on AWS EC2 instance. Having created an FTP user and installed vsftp, I kept getting a "connection timeout" from Sublime/SFTP. I decided to try the SSH key route. Here is my server setup in SFTP. It also gets "connection timeout." What could be the reason for this? Is this on the client or server side?
Now, before anyone suggests it, I do have port 22 as my SSH port in AWS Security Groups / Inbound Rules settings.

I blanked out some entries like server, password and keyname.

```js
// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",

"sync_down_on_open": true,
"sync_same_age": true,

"host": "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
"user": "ec2",
//"password": "******",
"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/home/user/",
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
"ssh_key_file": " ~/.ssh/file.pem",
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "~/.ssh/file.pem"],
"sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/Users/user/.ssh/file.pem"]
 //"sftp_flags": ["-o", IdentityFile="/Users/user/.ssh/file.pem"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
//"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
```

}

Comment: Try commenting out `"ssh_key_file"` and see if that works. Also, make sure your `.pem` file has the correct permissions - they should be `0400`.

Comment: MattDMo, I have done those things prior to my attempts with the username method. If I am using a basic FTP connection, then I should not need an SSH, am I correct?

Comment: No, but in the setting you show you're using `sftp`.

Comment: Also, I was able to play around with the settings (created another user and am trying the basic FTP method). I am now getting a successful connection but the following error: 

Connecting to FTP server "**.**.**.***" as "user" ..... success
Validating remote folder "/home/user/" .. failure (Folder not found)

The problem seems to be with the folder setting either in the SFTP plugin or EC2 server itself.

Comment: See my comment above. In my trying to get this fixed, I switched the methods a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
{
    "type": "sftp",
    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": false,
    "sync_down_on_open": false,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,
    "host": "1.2.3.4", //IPv4 Public IP in Instances > Desription tab of EC2 Dashboard
    "user": "ec2-user",
    "port": "22",
    "remote_path": "/var/www/html/",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    "connect_timeout": 10,
    "ssh_key_file": "C:/Users/me/Desktop/aws.ppk", //Generated ppk file using PuTTYgen
}
```